# Sobreposición con FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, next.js, tailwind, ts

Estoy usándolo en mi app con next/ts/tailwind, y recién he notado que se superpone a todo, he revisado todo el elemento en búsqueda de z-index y nada. En la imagen se ve el problema con el navbar pero ocurre con todos los otros elementos que deberían superponerese. ¿Alguna sugerencia de qué podría ser? He ahogado al chatgpt intentando descubrirlo y en la documentación de FullCalendar no encuentro algo específico sólo maneras de usar el css.
[image: Véase que queda sobre el Navbar]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.